# Benchmarking: Why is Play (Scala) throughput-latency curve not coming flat?

Tags: scala, performance, playframework, apachebench

I am doing performance benchmarking of my Play (Scala) web app. The application is hosted on a cloud server. I am using 2.5.x and Scala 2.11.11. I used Apache Bench to generate requests. One example command of using 'ab':
ab -n 10 -c 10 -T 'application/json'

For my APIs I am getting consistently a linear curve for Number of requests vs. Response time (ms). Here is one such data point:

```
50%      80%        90%
```

10  592      602        732
20  1002        1013       1014
50  2168    2222   2290
100 4177        4179       4222
200 8477    9459       9462

First column is the number of concurrent requests. Second, third and fourth columns are the "percentage of requests served within this time".
[image: Also attached image here of the graph]

Blue, Red and Orange bars represent respectively 50%, 80% and 90% the percentage of requests served within this time. The CPU load goes above 50% only when concurrent requests > 100.
These results are on my standard Play+Scala app without any specific optimizations e.g. I am using standard Action => Result controllers for APIs. The results are quite disappointing to me given that the system is partially loaded (CPU load < 50% and hardly any memory usage). The server has 2 CPUs + 8GB Mem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in how to measure a real response latency, than use [wrk2](https://github.com/giltene/wrk2) tool instead.

Here is a presentation of wrk2 author about how to measure latency and throughput to compare scalability of different systems or their configurations: https://www.infoq.com/presentations/latency-response-time

As an option use [Gatling](https://github.com/gatling/gatling) - it has properly implemented measuring to overcome a coordinated omission.

BTW if is possible than share your sources and scripts for testing. In history of the following repository you can find all that stuff for Play 2.5 version too: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/play

FYI: It is great to see that Java still in top-5, but Rust, Kotlin and Go are approaching quickly... and most pity that Scala frameworks are not based on top Java's... even NodeJs shown greater result than Netty and Undertow: https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r15&hw=ph&test=json